# MPAndroidChart doesn't Work properly with android 5 & 6

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

I'm struggling with using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) bar chart in android studio. it seems to not work properly at android 5 or 6 but it works fine at ver 4. In fact it doesn't fit to all their layout!

[Screen shot - Huawei honor 4x -  android 4.4.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StsY1.jpg)

[Screen shot - Samsung S7 -  android 6.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUmwe.jpg)

My configuraton:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "android.parsic.parstel"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.1'
}
```

my draw function:

```
public void DrawChart(List<Cls_TestResult_HistoryGraph> MyTestHistory, String ChartName) {

    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

    // no description text
    mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

    // enable touch gestures
    mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);

    // enable scaling and dragging
    mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    mChart.setScaleEnabled(false);

    mChart.setPinchZoom(true);

    mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);

    XAxis xAxisss = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxisss.setLabelCount(MyTestHistory.size(), true);
    //xAxisss.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxisss.setTextSize(0f);
    xAxisss.setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);


    setData(MyTestHistory, ChartName);

    mChart.animateX(1000);

    mChart.invalidate();

}

private void setData(List<Cls_TestResult_HistoryGraph> MyTestHistory, String ChartName) {

    ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for (Cls_TestResult_HistoryGraph TRH : MyTestHistory) {

        values.add(new Entry(MyTestHistory.indexOf(TRH), (float) TRH.result));
    }

    LineDataSet set1;

    if (mChart.getData() != null &&
            mChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
        set1 = (LineDataSet) mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
        set1.setValues(values);
        mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        // create a dataset and give it a type
        set1 = new LineDataSet(values, "");


        set1.setDrawFilled(true);
        set1.setFormLineDashEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{10f, 5f}, 0f));

        if (Utils.getSDKInt() >= 18) {
            // fill drawable only supported on api level 18 and above
            Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.fade_gray);
            set1.setFillDrawable(drawable);
        } else {
            set1.setFillColor(Color.GRAY);
        }

        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set1); // add the datasets

        // create a data object with the datasets
        LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);

        // set data
        mChart.setData(data);
    }
}
```

and my XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/LightBlue">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp" android:id="@+id/Labconfirm_TestResultList_HistorySection"
                android:background="@color/LabConfirm_TestList_Background">


                <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">


                    <android.parsic.parstel.CustomControl.UC_TextView_EnglishNormal
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/LabConfirm_TestList_CommentTextColor"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:layout_weight="0.33"
                        android:id="@+id/LabConfirm_TestList_ChartTestName"
                        android:text="1 of 2"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:linksClickable="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />


                    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                        android:id="@+id/chart1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Anyone can help me?

Ramin Hbb

Comment: Please make sure you are using the latest version of the library (3.0.1) and that your `targetSdkVersion` is 25 (the latest).

Apart from that, the code looks OK for the setup of your chart. If the above suggestions don't solve it, I think the problem is due to the layout (XML). In that case, you would need to edit the post to contain the [MCVE] for reproducing the problem

Comment: @DavidRawson thanks for replay.
1)I used  compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1' and I think it is the latest version.
2) I set  targetSdkVersion=19 as my app  should run on the android 4 to 6.Is it wrong? of course I mentioned my configuration at top of my question

Comment: @DavidRawson

3) And this is my xml layout:

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/chart1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

Comment: Also, you should always target the latest API even though you want your app to run on lower versions

Comment: I had a look at your XML. There is still probably enough to adequately diagnose the problem. However, 1. don't use weights inside a RelativeLayout 2. Add this attribute `android:layout_above="@id/LabConfirm_TestList_ChartTestName"` inside your LineChart 3. Don't use deprecated attribute `android:singleline=true` . If that doesn't fix it,try rebuilding your XML element by element from nothing in order to diagnose where things go wrong.

Comment: @DavidRawson tnx anyway... I'll check it

Comment: Just an update - I can't reproduce this problem. The chart setup is correct AFAIK. Also, the XML for adding the chart looks okay. It's probably the additional XML for that activity or fragment that is causing the issue.